# Como desabilitar modo (permissão) do arquivo no GIT?

Tags: linux, git, sistema-de-arquivos

Estou trabalhando com o `GIT` aqui na empresa onde trabalho, junto com mais dois programadores.

Toda vez que eu faço um `git pull`, cuja as alterações foram mandadas por esses dois programadores, sempre tenho problema com a permissão do arquivo ou da pasta que eles enviaram.

Percebi que esses dois programadores gostaram de executar os comandos do GIT depois de usar `sudo su` e logar com esse "Super usuário". Porém, eu não faço isso. Utilizo o meu usuário normalmente e, quando necessário, rodo sempre o comando `sudo` antes dos outros comandos.

E creio que isso seja o recomendado, pois alguns programas como `git`, `composer`, `bower` ou `nodejs`, geralmente recomendam a **não utilização do sudo** quando vamos rodá-los, justamente por conta das permissões de arquivos.

Parece-me que realmente é esse o problema. E toda vez, tenho que ficar executando o comando `sudo chmod -R 777 .` para resolver isso. E **isso está se tornando cansativo!**.

Suponhamos que eu não consiga convencer meus colegas de trabalho a parar de usar o `sudo su`, teria alguma maneira de desabilitar o  `modo` (os valores da permissão) do arquivo?

Ou seja, não quero que o `git` adicione mais as informações se um arquivo tem permissão de escrita ou não, e essas coisas.

Gostaria que todos os arquivos semprem fossem "reconhecidos" como 0777.

Como fazer isso no `GIT`? Como desabilitar esse `change mode` que sempre aparece quando dou um `git pull`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basta alterar a configuração `core.filemode` do repositório:

```
git config core.fileMode false
```

Se você quiser desabilitar isso para todos os repositórios do seu usuário, adicione a *flag* `--global`:

```
git config --global core.fileMode false
```

Comment: Muito bom, muito bom +1