# Permissão de arquivos GIT

Tags: git, osx, permissões

Todos os meus sistemas que tenho estão dando problema de permissão após eu dar um `git pull`, de forma que por exemplo eu tenho uma pasta onde são gerados os meus arquivos de js e css mimificado. Pasta assets/min/, após eu dar um pull eu preciso sempre de rodar `chmod -R 777 assets/min` para que eu possa alterar esses arquivos min, gera-los novamente no caso, qual seria a solução nesse caso para que eu não precise dar permissão toda vez que fizer um `pull`?

**Obs.: Meu sistema operacional é macOS High Sierra**

Comment: Você pode alterar  o umask ... Segue URL sobre http://www.itnerante.com.br/group/colunadoboechat/forum/topics/alterando-permiss-es-padr-es-no-linux-com-umask

Comment: Relacionada: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/131475/como-desabilitar-modo-permiss%c3%a3o-do-arquivo-no-git

Answer (score 1):

Tive esse problema há um tempo atrás. Resolvi da seguinte maneira:

1. Abra a pasta do seu repositório local com o Finder. Clique na pasta e pressione  ⌘I. Isso deve abrir as informações da pasta. Se aparecer um cadeado na janela, clique e digite a senha do seu Mac para dar permissões de escrita.
2. No final dessa janela, procure por "Sharing & Permissions". Lá tem uma tabela de permissões e usuários. No seu usuário, onde indica "(Me)", selecione "Read and Write".
3. Clique no ícone de configuração (engrenagem) e selecione "Apply to enclosed items".

Isso vai colocar permissões de escrita e leitura para todas as pastas, subpastas e arquivos no seu usuário para a pasta do seu repositório local. Se tiver dificuldades, usa [esse print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/llaYL.png) como referência.

Se por ventura você compartilha essa pasta com alguém na rede, é um pouco mais chato de resolver. Aí você pode tentar adicionar o seguinte no seu `.gitconfig`:

```
[core]
  repositoryformatversion = 0
  filemode = true
  bare = false
  logallrefupdates = true
  sharedRepository = group
```

Tem um blog mais detalhado sobre [aqui](http://briantanaka.com/blog/git/groupwrite.html).