# Visual Studio - GIT - 5000 changes

Tags: git

Gente, me ajudem ai...

Olha a imagem abaixo, qualquer tipo de alteração ela pede para subir para o GIT...

Como retirar isto, podem me ajudar

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Se alterou permissões da pasta, tente isso: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/131475/5878

Answer (score 1):

Aconteceu algo semelhante comigo, eu acidentalmente dei um `git add .` de tudo que tinha no meu desktop e todos os arquivos fora pra lista de *Changes* do *Commit*. Vou te explicar como eu resolvi.

Primeiro vc tem que descobrir a Raiz de onde foi feito o comando acidental. Pois na raiz dessa pasta vc precisa deletar o folder `.git`

Para isso vc pode fazer dessa forma. Use o comando

```
git rev-parse --show-toplevel
```

Repare na imagem que eu estou com o projeto **Hi** aberto, depois eu dei um `cd imgs` entrei na pasta **imgs**, ai quando eu dou o comando `git rev-parse --show-toplevel` ele mostra quem é o *folder* pai. É nesse *folder* que vai estar a pasta `.git` que vc tem que deletar

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

Agora repare que a pasta `.git` por default é uma arquivo do tipo oculto. O próprio Windows deixa essa pasta oculta, e mesmo dando um `dir` não vai mostrar o folder `.git` mesmo ele estando lá

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

Então para se certificar que o folder `.git` está no caminho certo vai no Windows Explorer e manda exibir as pastas ocultas. Vc vai ver algo como isso.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

Agora é só dar esse comando para remover a pasta `rm -rf .git`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Isso deve remover o tracking do projeto e sua lista vai voltar a ficar limpa.**

Comment: Muito Obrigado, deu certo...

Comment: @AlexLopes que bom que deu certo! Se a minha resposta te ajudou de alguma forma considere marca-la como Aceita, nesse ícone ✔ abaixo das setinhas no lado esquerdo da minha resposta :) assim o site não fica com perguntas abertas pendentes mesmo já tendo sido resolvidas.