# como fazer um git clone sem o repositório .git?

Tags: git, versionamento

Tenho um repositório onde guardo meus arquivos de front-end. Queria saber uma forma de fazer um "git clone" desse repo para dentro de uma pasta de um projeto (ex: um tema do wordpress), de forma que só venha os arquivos, sem a pasta ".git" (que cuidaria do versionamento). E não crie uma pasta nova para o repo, mas que o arquivos venha para meu diretório raiz do projeto(vulgo meu working directory).

Na verdade estou me esforçando pra entender o git com abordagem mais "*Plumbing Commands*", mas na documetação oficial é muito *hard/técnico* de entender. Nos tutoriais da internet é tudo muito *engessado e voltado para o simples*. Estou em busca de um meio termo para q eu possa avançar.

Tipo, no meu repo eu tenho meu projeto sass e minhas tarefas padrões com gulp (*que comportam perfeitamente minha demanda de projetos para internet*) e esse repo tem a intenção de evoluir sempre. Mas a ideia é chegar num comando git onde eu possa baixar os arquivos desse repo para um projeto novo para q eu agilize "o ambiente de desenvolvimento".

Comment: Vc quer por linha de comando? Pq não vai direto no site GitHub e faz o download do zip e coloca na pasta que vc quer? Manda exibir os arquivos ocultos e apaga a pasta .git se ela estiver lá.... As vezes isso pode te ajudar https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/356852/visual-studio-git-5000-changes/356914#356914

Comment: Por linha de comando, pois a intenção é q eu consiga automatizar com bash. acho que fiz uma pergunta bem precisa sobre isso.

Comment: @user7069 se você for clonar, você necessitará do `.git`. O mais padrão seria você fazer um build e deixá-lo acessível para fazer o download. Isso fica mais explícito quando você está fazendo algo que precise passar por compilação antes de ir pra produção, mas também pode ser feito em PHP.

Answer (score 2):

Você não consegue isso com o clone, mas é possível com o `archive` ou `checkout-index`:

```
git archive master | tar -x -C /somewhere/else
```

O `git archive` vai criar um pacote com o código comitado na sua branch e em seguida você pode extraí-lo com o `tar`.

```
git checkout-index -a -f --prefix=/destination/path/
```

O `git checkout-index` com a flag `-a` copia todos os arquivos no index e o `-f` forçar sobrescrever os arquivos no destino caso eles já existam.

No `--prefix` você define o caminho que deseja copiar seus arquivo. Atenção para a última `/`, se você esquece-la seu arquivo irá para um destino errado com um prefixo chamado `path`.

Referencia: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/160608/do-a-git-export-like-svn-export/160719